# Hide/Remove scroll bar from Vanillamodal iframes

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, modal-dialog, hide

I'm using Vanillamodal (http://cocopon.me/app/vanillabox/demo.html) to generate iframes but I'd like to be able to have the scroll bars of the iframe hidden. I've tried putting the following into CSS and adding the overflow command to the script but the scrollbars still appear.

```
    <li><a id="about-me" href="../about me/about me.html" >about me</a></li>

    iframe {
    overflow: hidden;
    }      


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Vanillaboxes         
    $('html').css('overflow','hidden');
    $('#about-me').vanillabox({
    animation: 'none',
    closeButton: true,
    preferredWidth: 400,
    preferredHeight: 300,
    repositionOnScroll: true,
    type: 'iframe'              
    });             
    });     
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, however this needs to be inline of the html. If you provide a fiddle or some more info I can look at it further.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure of the semantics to do that. http://jsbin.com/fifuruqa/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Figured it out. I just add                                                <style>
 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
 } 
  

  
</style>